# Methods for recursive concatenations on user defined classes in R?

Tags: r, recursion

All the concatenation functions in R can be rewritten as recursive functions. For instance, I could use `c` as a binary operator and I could define a new `concat` function as

```
concat <- function(...) {
  Reduce(c, ...)
}
```

and `concat` would function as `c` actually functions in R base.

R syntactically uses many such functions, for instance `c` for vectors and lists, `cbind` for arrays, data.frames and matrices. When defining new object classes, it makes sense to create a method for combining them using a function which takes `...` as an argument.

I know R can match methods to objects when they are the first object in the argument list, but what if I define a method like

```
concat <- function(...) {
   UseMethod('concat')
}

concat.numeric <- function(...) {
   c(...)
}

concat.character <- function(...) {
   c(...)
}

myCon <- function(charPart, numPart) {
  out <- list(charPart=charPart, numPart=numPart)
  class(out) <- "myClass"
  out
}

concat.myClass <- function(...) {
  myCon(sapply(..., `[[`, 'charPart'), sapply(..., `[[`, 'numPart'))
}

> concat(4, 6, 'a')
"4" "6" "a"

> myObj1 <- myCon('a', 1)
> myObj2 <- myCon('b', 2)

> concat(myObj1, myObj2)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
object 'p' of mode 'function' was not found
```

At what point does R identify the types of arguments supplied to `concat`? How can I convince R to attempt to cast arguments to `concat` up to my specific object class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not quite passing what you think to `sapply` you need to put it in `list(...)` so `sapply` can iterate through the elements rather than parsing them as extra arguments in the wrong place.

```
concat.myClass <- function(...) 
{
   myCon(sapply(list(...), `[[`, 'charPart'), sapply(list(...), `[[`, 'numPart'))
}


> myObj1
$charPart
[1] "a"

$numPart
[1] 1

attr(,"class")
[1] "myClass"
> myObj2
$charPart
[1] "b"

$numPart
[1] 2

attr(,"class")
[1] "myClass"
```

this then gives:

```
> concat(myObj1, myObj2)
$charPart
[1] "a" "b"

$numPart
[1] 1 2

attr(,"class")
[1] "myClass"
```

.. which I presume is what you want???

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for the debug. I guess then there's nothing wrong with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No problem. On what you are trying to do... it's fine so long as you are not designing code for heavy manipulation of big series of data as R is not compiled and deep recursive functions (e.g. Fibonacci, prime number finders, newtons method) are better not programmed this way... otherwise fine.